# Laravel Homestead reports incorrect version of Vagrant and thus does not let me run the VM

Tags: php, linux, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm running Linux Mint 19.3 and have set up a Homestead Vagrant box many times before. I'm following [the simple directions on the official site](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/homestead). I have Homestead installed and initiated (cloned from the release branch), downloaded the most recent version of Vagrant 2.2.6, configured my Homestead.yaml and hosts files, but when I run `vagrant up`, I get:

```
version to satisfy the following version requirements:

  >= 2.2.4

You are running Vagrant 2.0.2, which does not satisfy
these requirements. Please change your Vagrant version or update
the Vagrantfile to allow this Vagrant version. However, be warned
that if the Vagrantfile has specified another version, it probably has
good reason to do so, and changing that may cause the environment to
not function properly.
```

This is a fresh install of mint and has no other version of vagrant on the machine. I've grepped the whole of my drive for `2.0.2` with no results. Why is it reporting the wrong version and not letting my run until I "upgrade"?

Comment: Do you get the following output when running `vagrant --version`: Vagrant 2.2.6?

Comment: No, it says 2.0.2. I've just downloaded the latest vagrant and can't figure out where that number is coming from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have accidentally installed an earlier version of the Vagrant program. Below are the steps outlined to delete the current installation and download a new one.

Uninstalling Vagrant:

```
rm -rf /opt/vagrant
rm -f /usr/bin/vagrant
```

Make sure you have VirtualBox installed:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

Update package list:

```
sudo apt update
```

Download Vagrant 2.2.6 using Curl:

```
curl -O https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.6/vagrant_2.2.6_x86_64.deb
```

Once downloaded:

```
sudo apt install ./vagrant_2.2.6_x86_64.deb
```

Verify successful installation:

```
vagrant --version
```

Expected output:

```
Vagrant 2.2.6
```